# Create Python package from binary-only shared objects

Tags: python, pip, shared-libraries, setuptools, python-packaging

I have a Python module distributed as binary-only shared-object (`.so`) file, provided for each different Python version.
Right now the only way to use this module is to manually export the `PYTHONPATH` variable.
My goal is to create a regular Python package (wheel) that could be managed by `pip` that install the right so-file depending on the interpreter version.

By looking at the documentation of [setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html) I have not find so far how to write a `pyproject.toml` for this specific purpose.
I would need some guidance on how to define a Python project file specifying a target so-file for each Python version, as opposed to the usual way of indicating the source directory.